# CTRL KeyPress event is fired trough scrolling with TouchPad

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, gesture

I'm trying to track the control-key when it's pressed and released.
While everything seemed fine in the beginning, but when scrolling with my touch-pad on my HP laptop on Windows 11 the KeyPress event is fired automatically.

Is this a Windows thing and is *normal behavior* or is it a *bug* in tkinter?

My code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
ctrl_pressed = None
    
def check_ctrl(event):
    print(ctrl_pressed, 'checked')
    
def track_ctrl(event):
    global ctrl_pressed
    if (et:=event.type.name) == 'KeyPress':
        ctrl_pressed = True
    elif et == 'KeyRelease':
        ctrl_pressed = False
    print(ctrl_pressed, 'tracked')
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<MouseWheel>', check_ctrl)
root.bind('<KeyPress-Control_L>', track_ctrl)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Control_L>', track_ctrl)
root.mainloop()
```

- Using the MouseWheel first will output `None`--as expected.
- Using
  the Touchpad first will output `True`--not expected.
- Pressing the
  Key will output first `True` then `False`--as expected.

It seems to be an generated event:

```py
def track_ctrl(event):
    print(event.send_event)
```

This produces `True` with touchpad.

---

> I'm using patchlevel of Tkinter `8.6.12`, and Python version `3.11.0`

Comment: Can't reproduce with a Dell XPS: I get `None` when using Touchpad first (Windows 10).

Comment: I get results True when I use scrolling buttons and when I release False prints out with Windows 10 Pro, HP

Comment: Can't reproduce with `tkinter.TclVersion = 8.6`, python version `3.11.0` and Windows 11. `track_ctrl` isn't called unless I press the ctrl key. Also please don't assume that is there is a `KeyPress`, there must be a `KeyRelease` in the future - it is possible for one program to receive the ctrl key press and another to receive the corresponding key release.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks for taking the time. I currently belief that my Laptop is producing the issue. Could you please add the brand of your Notebook/Laptop or what you have used for testing ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 10 pro and Python 3.11 I can't reproduce this behavioure.
You could try using keyboard rather then tkinter for your event listening.

Here is your code with `keyboard.is_pressed` rather then checking `event.type`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from keyboard import is_pressed
ctrl_pressed = None

def check_ctrl(event):
    print(ctrl_pressed, 'checked')

def track_ctrl(event):
    global ctrl_pressed
    if is_pressed('ctrl'):
        ctrl_pressed = True
    else:
        ctrl_pressed = False
    print(ctrl_pressed, 'tracked')

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<MouseWheel>', check_ctrl)
root.bind('<KeyPress-Control_L>', track_ctrl)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-Control_L>', track_ctrl)
root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well I do know how to work around it, but thanks for your try. Please take also a look at the bounty notification, I'm well aware it does not apply for everyone, rather I'm curious where the error exact comes from and if its possible to fix it inside python and tkinter. In addition I do believe the exact same behavior would apply to `keyboard` module, since I think it is related to my hardware, however there is also the fact of a `generated event` so not that sure about it.

Comment: Yeah I saw the bounty message. I am no system expert so I can't help with that, but i thought I'd suggest an alternative, so that you can advance on your project if that is your priority.

Comment: Thank you, it might help someone else in the future.